# Drawing a line with asterisks on the console

Tags: java, drawing

How can I draw a line with asterisks on the console? I will accept the coordinates from the user (x1,y1), (x2,y2).

Comment: can I use DDA algorithm to draw a line??

Comment: It's "asterisks". What have you tried? Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a reasonably capable console, you can combine the ANSI escape code for [*Horizontal and Vertical Position (HPV)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) with [*Bresenham's line drawing algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Addendum: As this is homework, [*Bresenham's algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) is overkill. Because it's a common assignment, you might look at how [others have approached the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bhomework%5D+triangle+asterisk). In addition, you can edit your question to include your code and other details about the assignment.

Comment: Can I draw it with for loops?Of course there will be errors but i can find an approximated triangle

Comment: I don't see why not, but why go to all the trouble?

Comment: teacher said that it is difficult to draw exactly a triangle but you can find a shape like triangle with for loops.

Comment: It's a popular assignment; I've elaborated above.

Answer (score 0):

I would first write a method that prints out a star at a given x-coordinate. Such as given an x coordinate 7, print out 6 spaces and then an asterisk.

I would then determine the slope (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) make sure that x1 is the point with the higher y value(on a higher line, but this might be a lower actual value). Then increment the x value by the slope on each iteration through a loop

```
for(i = y1; i<=y2;i++)
 asteriskprintfunction(x1+(slope*i));
```

that should do it.

edit:
had accidentally made the loop with x values and since you want to go line by line, you should use the y values. also clarified how to pick which point is (x1,y1)

Comment: in my mind, this makes a lot of sense, but just let me know if this is confusing (also, I didn't want to give TOO MUCH away as it is homework)